# Не возвращается результат в переменной jQuery

Tags: jquery

Не могу понять, почему не срабатывает калькуляция в коде:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($('#type1:checked')) {
    var shed   = base+distance+size1+rubber;
  } else if ($('#type2:checked')) {
    var shed   = base+distance+size2+rubber;
  } else if ($('#type3:checked')) {
    var shed   = base+distance+size3+rubber;
  } else if ($('#type4:checked')) {
    var shed   = base+distance+size3+rubber;
  } else ($('#type5:checked')) {
    var shed   = base2+distance+size4+rubber;
  }
  $('#last__par_count').html(shed);
});
```

В тег с id=last__par_count не заносится результат вычислений.
Во всех имеющихся переменных есть значения.

Comment: `} else ($('#type5:checked')) {` - сынтаксическая ошибка, весь код не выполняется.

Comment: А можете посоветовать лучший плагин для atom, который более полно проверяет код в реальном времени на синт. ошибки? Конкретно js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неправильно проверяете чекбокс:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var shed = "";
  if ($('#type1').is(':checked')) {
    shed = base+distance+size1+rubber;
  } else if ($('#type2').is(':checked')) {
    shed = base+distance+size2+rubber;
  } else if ($('#type3').is(':checked')) {
    shed = base+distance+size3+rubber;
  } else if ($('#type4').is(':checked')) {
    shed = base+distance+size3+rubber;
  } else if ($('#type5').is(':checked')) {
    shed = base2+distance+size4+rubber;
  }
  $('#last__par_count').html(shed);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А можете посоветовать лучший плагин для atom, который более полно проверяет код в реальном времени на синт. ошибки? Конкретно js

Answer (score 2):

Кроме ошибки синтаксиса, все условия неверные - всегда будет выполняться блок кода под первым `if`-ом, так как даже пустой объект-обертка jQuery соответствует булевскому `true`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var shed = "";
  if ($('#type1:checked').length) {
    shed = base + distance + size1 + rubber;
  } else if ($('#type2:checked').length) {
    shed = base + distance + size2 + rubber;
  } else if ($('#type3:checked').length) {
    shed = base + distance + size3 + rubber;
  } else if ($('#type4:checked').length) {
    shed = base + distance + size3 + rubber;
  } else if ($('#type5:checked').length) {
    shed = base2 + distance + size4 + rubber;
  }
  $('#last__par_count').html(shed);
});
```

Comment: А почему не `.is("checked")`? Это ведь и понятнее, и никаких неявных преобразования из числа в bool.

Comment: @Regent Согласен. Хотел свести изменения кода из вопроса к минимуму.

Comment: А можете посоветовать лучший плагин для atom, который более полно проверяет код в реальном времени на синт. ошибки? Конкретно js